# get compile error in perl program

Tags: perl

I installed Strawberry Perl to run the rouge program in Windows. But when I want to run my program, I receive an error message that you can see on the image:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Cwd;
$curdir=getcwd;
$ROUGE="c:\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";
chdir("sample-test");
$cmd="$ROUGE -e c:\data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a DUC2002-    ROUGE.in.26.spl.xml > c:\sample-output\output.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
chdir($curdir);
```

Error:
Missing braces on \o{} at C:\runROUGE-test1.pl line 7, near "$ROUGE"
Execution of C:\runROUGE-test1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: image doesn't show up.  What's the error message?

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: use single quote for $ROUGE='c:\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl'; and others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To produce the string

```
c:\data
```

using a double-quoted string literal, you need to escape the slash.

```
"c:\\data"
```

You have other similar problems.

By the way, you should always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 0):

A backslash has a special meaning in a Perl string. To get a literal backslash you need to double the backslash (as ikegami pointed out).

But it's also worth mentioning that you don't need to use backslashes. Perl on Windows interprets a forward slash as a directory separator too. And that doesn't need to be doubled as it has no special meaning in a quoted string.

```
$ROUGE = "c:/ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";
```

p.s. Please get into the habit of adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to your Perl code.